# Easy to follow video lectures or online help on measure-theoretic mathematical statistics

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, references, measure-theory

Due to some unexpected events, I was not able to follow my measure-theoretic mathematical statistics classes for a while and now I have to cover these materials (chapter 1 of Jun Shao's book and relevant materials from Billingsley) within a week to catch up with the class. I find these books overwhelming with so short time at hand, given that I have other courses too. Is there a series of video lectures or other materials that can help me understand the basic concepts (basic measure theory, measurable space, sigma-additivity, MCT, Fatou's lemma, convergence, etc.) to be able to solve exercise problems on my own? I'm also wondering if any sort of online tutoring is available to cover materials in about a week or so.

Comment: I think before taking measure-theoretic *statistics* (and probability), you need to have the pre-requisite **measure theory**! Have you already done a course? From which text? McDonald and Weiss is a really good bridge for statistical theory. Simply searching YouTube shows complete lecture sets from profs at reputable universities across the globe.

Comment: I had courses that used part of measure theory, but I didn't take a full course of measure theory (unfortunately). I can find some courses on YouTube, but the sequence in which they are covered may differ from the book I'm following. With so short time at hand, I'm having trouble with which one to start with.

Comment: This verges on opinion-based, but I **really** think you need that RA basis before jumping in. I did my measure-theoretic stats course from the Fergusson text, and you're assumed to know a $\sigma$-measure, you're expected to know Fubini's theorem, Fatou-Lebesgue's theorem, ... I had RA from McDonald and Weiss prior to this, and that text is praised for being really focused on applied work in numerical analysis and statistics.

Comment: In your place I'd stick with lecture notes and recommended books. The most important thing is to do exercises. It is the only way to understand this subject. Do a lot of problems before moving to the next chapter. They may seem overwhelming at first, but I promise that you'll start getting used to this thinking at some points. Billingsley's a horrible text for a beginner, but it is doable even for a non mathematician. I know it because I did it myself. It's great to know measure theory, but you can command the content even without it, sort of learning it while flying. YOU CAN DO IT

Comment: I did not encounter a good measure theory class online, unfortunately. I also think it has a lot of stuff that is not strictly required for measure theoretic probability theory, at least not on the first run. Neither did I see a measure theoretic probability theory class for non-math and non-stats folks. If you're in an applied field such as quant finance, then high brow approach taught in math/stats programs can be overkill. You don't need to know laws of physics to drive a car